# C#: Simulate Mouse Click Without DLLImport

Tags: c#, mouse

There are already many solutions for simulating mouse clicks in C#. However, they all use DLLImport, which is for unmanaged code. The problem with this is unmanaged code isn't garbage-collected automatically and can be a bit (1s or 0s!) hacky. However, I found [this Microsoft Developer website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548(v=vs.110).aspx) that shows a possible solution (but it wasn't clear):

> 1. Create a MouseEventArgs whose Button property is set to the MouseButtons.Right value.
> 2. Call the OnMouseClick method with this MouseEventArgs as the argument.

Does anyone know a way to simulate a mouse click without DLLImport?

So far, I found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.mouse.click.aspx, but this is for UI Testing only. In it, it says Mouse.Click(Point) will click at a specified point. However, it relies on Visual Studio's own Test Tools namespace, which means the final application will not be entirely stand-alone.

Comment: The lack of garbage collection is no problem if you don't allocate unmanaged resources. Calling functions in unmanaged DLLs (i.e. with `DllImport`) doesn't automatically imply that you will be allocating unmanaged resources. Also, what's unclear about calling the mouse click event handler? Are you trying to simulate a mouse click in your application, or are you trying to make your C# program push a mouse click event in some other application?

Comment: Just a mouse click for any app. Basically, I'm trying to build a task automator in C#.

Comment: @JimMischel Good point by the way. So far, I can easily MOVE the mouse pointer without DLLIMPORT using the point object. However, I can't simulate a mouse CLICK.

Comment: Putting a mouse click in another application's message queue is non-trivial. You'll almost certainly have to call Windows API functions in unmanaged code for that.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for your reply! So there's nothing close to a mouse click that doesn't require DLLIMPORT?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.

Comment: @JimMischel If there is no possible answer as of now, should I close down this question, or leave it for future viewers to try to answer?